# How to make pydantic class fields immutable?

Tags: python, python-3.6, pydantic

I am trying to create a pydantic class with Immutable class fields (not instance fields).

Here is my base code:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class ImmutableModel(BaseModel):
    _name: str = "My Name"
    _age: int = 25

ImmutableModel._age = 26

print("Class variables:")
print(f"Name: {ImmutableModel._name}")
print(f"Age: {ImmutableModel._age}")
```

Output:

```
Class variables:
Name: My Name
Age: 26
```

I tried using the `Config` class inside my `ImmutableModel` to make fields immutable. But it seems like it only works for instance class fields.

```
class Config:
    allow_mutation = False
```

FYI, I use `Python 3.6.13` and `pydantic==1.9.2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a field which is immutable after being set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70648645/create-a-field-which-is-immutable-after-being-set)

Comment: The solution works for instance variable, but I want this to happen on class variables `__name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, I tried to achieve creating immutable `Class` and `Instance` using pydantic module.

Now I were able to manage it using native method itself. Since this was completely defined by me and immutable, its fine to have no validation.

```
class ImmutableMetaclass(type):
    
    def __setattr__(cls, name, value):
        raise AttributeError("Cannot create or set class attribute '{}'".format(name))

class MyImmutableClass(metaclass=ImmutableMetaclass):
    
    # Define all allowed class attributes here
    CONSTANT_1 = 1

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        raise AttributeError("Cannot create or set class or instance attribute '{}'".format(name))
```

```
immutable_class = MyImmutableClass
immutable_class.CONSTANT_1 = 100
immutable_class.CONSTANT_2 = 200

immutable_instance = MyImmutableClass()
immutable_instance.CONSTANT_1 = 100
immutable_instance.CONSTANT_3 = 300
```

All the above code raises AttributeError.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me on `pydantic==1.9.2`.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class ImmutableModel(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(default="My Name")
    age: int = Field(default=25)
    
    class Config:
        allow_mutation = False

# Defining an object of ImmutableModel with default values for name and age
m = ImmutableModel()  

# This raises an error
m.age = 100
```

That solution only works for *instance* variables. To make it work for *class* variables, one way to ensure class attributes are not mutable is to mess with the metaclass as shown below:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from pydantic.main import ModelMetaclass

class ImmutableMeta(ModelMetaclass):
    IMMUTABLE_ATTRS = ['_name']

    def __setattr__(cls, name, value):
        if hasattr(cls, name):
            for attr in cls.IMMUTABLE_ATTRS:
                assert name != attr, f"Cannot modify class attribute '{attr}'"
        super().__setattr__(name, value)

class ImmutableModel(BaseModel, metaclass=ImmutableMeta):
    _name: str = 'This should not change'
    name: str = Field(default="This should not change when accessing through instance of class")

    class Config:
        allow_mutation = False

# Defining an object of ImmutableModel with default values for name and age
m = ImmutableModel()  

# This raises an error because of 'allow_mutation=False' in ImmutableModel Config
m.name = 'new name'  

# This raises an error since '_name' is not accessible from instance
m._name = 'new name' 

# This raises an error since '_name' is not modifiable
ImmutableModel._name = 'new name'
```

Note that the solution above is effectively overriding pydantic internal functionality which could cause unprecedented issues depending on your implementation. **Use with caution.**

Comment: Yes, This works for instance variable. Can we make this for class variables too `__name`

Comment: @arudsekaberne I want to clarify. In the question you are using `_name` (with a _single_ underscore), but in your previous comment you are using `__name` (with _double_ underscore). [Using single vs double underscores mean different things](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1301346/2745495) in Python classes so the possible solution to make them immutable might be different. Which one do you need?

Comment: I would like to go with double underscore `__name`

Comment: Understood. Your requirement is quite interesting. I've added edits that may help. Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: @sud, This works pretty well. But lets say I have 100 immutable class variables, in this case I have to alter `IMMUTABLE_ATTRS = ['_name']` for all the variables right?

Comment: Well all your pydantic classes can have the same metaclass and that metaclass can have a complete list of immutable attributes. Also, I'm curious to know what your use case is (if possible)

Comment: The use case is simple, I would like to use this class variable across many subfiles (which has to be immutable). In terms of performance and memory usage, accessing a class variable directly is generally more efficient than creating an instance to access the class variable.

Comment: Is it possible can we make this dynamic? ` IMMUTABLE_ATTRS = ['_name']`

Comment: I see. What do you exactly mean by dynamic? You could create a separate list outside of the metaclass definition and assign that list to IMMUTABLE_ATTRS. Does that work?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can set the field to be `frozen` individualy:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class ImmutableModel(BaseModel):
    _name: str = Field(default="My Name", frozen=True)
    _age: int = Field(default=25, frozen=True)
```

Comment: I can still change the values

Comment: @arudsekaberne I missed the part than metioned "class variables", my bad. Let me scratch my brain a bit. Pretty sure we can come up with something. Im curious what would be the use case? I don't think I saw `pydantic` beeing used in that manner. Does the `class` have to be a `BaseModel`?

Comment: The class doesn't has to be a `Basemodel`, we can achieve this using `@property` dunder method. But the problem occurs when number of variables gets increased (The code becomes messy).

The use case is simple, I would like to use this class variable across many subfiles. In terms of performance and memory usage, accessing a class variable directly is generally more efficient than creating an instance to access the class variable.